# required textfield isn't filled with sendkeys

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

I'm starting with selenium and java. I'm experimenting with this https://www.argenta.nl/hypotheek/hypotheek-berekenen#/formulier website. (it's a mortgage calculator) I'm stuck at the point where I have to select my job (dienstverband) and fill in the amount of income (bruto jaarinkomen) and click on the button 'ga verder'.

The button 'ga verder'validates if the field income has been filled. In my script I fill in this field 'income' with this line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("orientationCalculatorCtrlCalculatorMainApplicantIncomePermanentThisYearIncome")).sendKeys("51000");
```

But when I click on the button 'ga verder'nothing has been filled.(system gives a red notification) I thought send keys was a right option for filling in required textfields. Who'sable to help me out.

my whole testscript:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Esmee\\IdeaProjects\\seleniumTestArgenta\\src\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.argenta.nl");
    WebElement element;

    //opening orientation calculator (code akkoord)
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/header/div/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/header/div/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]/div/div/div/a[2]/div[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/article[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/a")).click();

    //wait for 10 seconds
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //clicking on button 'ga verder'gives a notification (Code Akkoord)
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/article[1]/div/form/div/ui-view[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/button")).click();

    //Uw situatie, select radiobutton no (= value 1 ), then push button 'ga verder'.

    element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='1']"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/article[1]/div/form/div/ui-view[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/button")).click();

    //wait for page to load, select income, fill in 51000
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"orientationCalculatorCtrlCalculatorMainApplicantIncomeVariant\"]"));

    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("orientationCalculatorCtrlCalculatorMainApplicantIncomeVariant")));
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Vast contract");
    driver.findElement(By.name("orientationCalculatorCtrlCalculatorMainApplicantIncomePermanentThisYearIncome")).sendKeys("51000");

    //pushing button 'ga verder' (system verifies input)
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/article[1]/div/form/div/ui-view[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/button"));
    executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
WebElement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("nameOfTheElementHere"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(yourElement).click();
act.sendKeys("51000");
act.build().perform();
```

Or:

```
WebElement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathHere"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", yourElement);
```

Or it could simply be a wait issue, in which case:

```
WebElement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathHere"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(yourElement)).click();
```